# does python utilize PATH environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pythonpath

My python script is being called by `kea-dhcp`, which has capability of executing external scripts (https://kea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arm/hooks.html#run-script-run-script-support-for-external-hook-scripts for details)

```
import subprocess
...
subprocess.check_output(('bridge', arg1, arg2 ...), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Where does `python` take information about location of `bridge` binary? I'm getting an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bridge': 'bridge'
```

I don't think it has anything to do with `PYTHONPATH` since it is not a problem of importing modules. What can be possibly wrong?

**UPDATE**
Following Charles Duffy's suggestion, I did:

```
res = subprocess.check_output([shutil.which('bridge'), '-j', 'fdb', 'show'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

but got error (it points to above `subprocess` line):

```
   File "/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
     **kwargs).stdout
   File "/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
   File "/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
     restore_signals, start_new_session)
   File "/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1278, in _execute_child
     executable = os.fsencode(executable)
   File "/lib64/python3.6/os.py", line 800, in fsencode
     filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
 TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I can't see what is wrong with that, looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Honestly, the first place I'd go would be logging `PATH` as seen by your Python process, and inspecting it with the location of the `bridge` executable you mean to run in mind. I added an answer suggesting the documentation-approved best-practice approach, but assuming you're on a common UNIXlike, the default behavior should generally be appropriate.

Comment: Is `bridge` actually on your path?  Are you able to execute `bridge` at a command line?

Comment: Yes, it is on my path, `bridge` is available.

Comment: Not your interactive PATH, but the Python interpreter's PATH. Validate that they're the same.

Comment: (that's what I was instructing you to do with _my very first comment_, when asking you to *log `PATH` as seen by your Python process*)

Comment: If `shutil.which('bridge)'` returns `None`, that tells us `bridge` isn't in your `PATH`. I'd guess maybe you were testing as root, which has `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` in the PATH, at your command line; then trying to run your Python script in a context that lacks those entries.

Answer (score 1):

How unqualified names are handled by `subprocess` depends on which operating system you're on. *Sometimes* `PATH` is honored; *never* is `PYTHONPATH` used for the purpose.

To explicitly perform a PATH lookup, change your code to use `shutil.which()`:

```
import shutil, subprocess

subprocess.check_output([shutil.which('bridge'), arg1, arg2], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

---

Quoting from https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor (formatting from the original) --

> **Warning** For maximum reliability, use a fully qualified path for the executable. To search for an unqualified name on `PATH`, use [`shutil.which()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which). On all platforms, passing [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) is the recommended way to launch the current Python interpreter again, and use the `-m` command-line format to launch an installed module.
>
> Resolving the path of executable (or the first item of *args*) is platform dependent. For POSIX, see [`os.execvpe()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execvpe), and note that when resolving or searching for the executable path, *cwd* overrides the current working directory and env can override the PATH environment variable. For Windows, see the documentation of the `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` parameters of WinAPI `CreateProcess`, and note that when resolving or searching for the executable path with `shell=False`, *cwd* does not override the current working directory and *env* cannot override the `PATH` environment variable. Using a full path avoids all of these variations.

Comment: `shutil.which()` returning `None` tells you that it agrees that `bridge` isn't in the PATH.

Comment: _shutil.which() returning None tells you that it agrees that bridge isn't in the PATH._

Then this means that PATH passed to `python` interpreter is not complete, or it is not available. For whatever reason.

Comment: Right. Have you adjusted your Python program to log `os.environ['PATH']`?

Comment: _Right. Have you adjusted your Python program to log os.environ['PATH']?_

Yes, I did `print(os.environ['PATH'])` and get `KeyError: 'PATH'`, so python does not know `PATH`.

Comment: There's your problem, then. How is the Python process started?

Comment: I updated my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `kea-dhcp` does not export system environment variables to scripts it executes, it only supplies its specific environment. Discovered this via `os.environ`. The only solution to this is provide the full pass to `bridge` command (or any other launched in this context).

Comment: Easier to tell `kea-dhcp`, instead of directly running your Python script, to run `/usr/bin/env PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin /path/to/your-python-script` -- assuming that `bridge` is in one of those three locations; amend appropriately otherwise.

Comment: That said, under the circumstances, I'd suggest deleting the question and asking a new one, and posting this answer there. This is still posed as a question _about Python_, but Python has nothing to do with the problem at all; if you'd answered all the comments on the question asking you to confirm that `PATH` was correct in an accurate manner, we would have gotten to a solution much, _much_ earlier.